# CodinGame (React test) : I don't understand the answer

Tags: reactjs, react-props

This is the demo for the React tests in CodinGame :

"From the following code snippet, what will be the color of "Hello world!" (line 11) after the "Change color" button is pressed ?"

https://www.codingame.com/assessment/fileservlet?id=16114156909252

a. red
b. green 
c. this code will throw an error
d. default color dependant on browser

The answer is a. red, but I don't understand why it's not b. green.
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be having error.As your parent class
return method is

```
render(){
    return()//here is the error
     <div>
     ...
     </div>)
   }
```

it should be like

```
render(){
    return(
     <div>
     ...
     </div>)
   }
```

This can give right result or upload your full code as text so we can have look and can test.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right! 
This is not my code, it's just a quizz.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed with Rajan, BUT I think this quizz is more focus about that it's a very bad practice to assign a local state with props from parents

```
this.state = { color: props.color }
```

Why ? Because this local state will never be updated with the new props. Indeed, the constructor is call just once, the local state is set with the color prop value and will never change.

Comment: And, this is scenario, where you need to think of, which state belong to which component.  In this case, color is state for Child component.

Answer (score 0):

you must bind the handler function

```
constructor(props) {
...
this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
}
.
.
changeColor() {
      this.setState({color: 'green'});
   }
return (
...
<button onClick={this.changeColor} >change color </button>
)
```